# CUDA Texture Cache seems to have the wrong data?

Tags: image-processing, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I've been writing CUDA code for quite a while, but I'm just now getting up to speed on how to use the texture cache.

Using the `simpleTexture` example from the Nvidia SDK for inspiration, I coded a simple example that uses the texture cache. The host copies the Lena image to the GPU and binds it as a texture. The kernel just copies the contents of the texture cache into an output array.

Oddly, the result (see the all-gray image below the code) is doesn't match the input. **Any thoughts about what might be going wrong?**

Code (look at `texCache_dummyKernel`):

```
texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex; //declare texture reference for 2D float texture

//note: tex is global, so no input ptr is needed
__global__ void texCache_dummyKernel(float* out, const int width, const int height){ //copy tex to output
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //my index into "big image"
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = y*width+x;

    if(x < width && y < height)
        out[idx] = tex2D(tex, y, x);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){        
    cv::Mat img = getRawImage("./Lena.pgm");
    img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);
    float* hostImg = (float*)&img.data[0];
    int width = img.cols; int height = img.rows;

    dim3 grid;  dim3 block;
    block.x = 16;  block.y = 16;
    grid.x = width/block.x + 1;          
    grid.y = height/block.y + 1;

    cudaArray *dImg; //cudaArray*, not float*
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0, cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);        
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaMallocArray(&dImg, &channelDesc, width, height));
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaMemcpyToArray(dImg, 0, 0, hostImg, width*height*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    setTexCacheParams(); //defined below
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaBindTextureToArray(tex, dImg, channelDesc)); //Bind the array to the texture

    float* dResult; //device memory for output
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaMalloc((void**)&dResult, sizeof(float)*width*height));

    texCache_dummyKernel<<<grid, block>>>(dResult, width, height); //dImg isn't an input param, since 'tex' is a global variable
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaGetLastError()); //make sure kernel didn't crash

    float* hostResult = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*width*height);
    CHECK_CUDART(cudaMemcpy(hostResult, dResult, sizeof(float)*width*height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    outputProcessedImage(hostResult, width, height, "result.png"); //defined below
}
```

I should probably provide a couple of helper functions that I used above:

```
void setTexCacheParams(){ //configuration directly pulled from simpleTexture in nvidia sdk
    tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    tex.normalized = true;    // access with normalized texture coordinates
}

void outputProcessedImage(float* processedImg, int width, int height, string out_filename){
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(height, width, CV_32FC1);
    for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
            img.at<float>(i,j) = processedImg[i*width + j]; //just grab the 1st of the 4 pixel spaces in a uchar4

    img.convertTo(img, CV_8UC1); //float to uchar
    vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(9);
    cv::imwrite(out_filename, img, compression_params);
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

---

- Sorry that this post is such a wall of code! I'd appreciate any advice on making code like this more concise.
- I used OpenCV for the file I/O above...hope this isn't confusing.
- When I change the kernel to read the input image from a 1D `float*` array, and I keep pretty much everything else the same, I get the correct result.

Comment: Despite writing "access with normalized texture coordinates" in your code, it doesn't look like that is what your kernel does....

Comment: Could you tell me a bit more about what you mean?

Comment: ah, you're a wizard. with a bit of trial-and-error in setting up the texture properties, these settings allowed the code to produce the right solution: `tex.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp; tex.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp; tex.normalized = false;`. Also, I reversed x and y: `out[idx] = tex2D(tex, x, y);`.

Comment: I'm not sure *why* `tex.normalized=false` is the right thing to do. If you understand, feel free to write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original code, you had initialised the texture to use *normalised coordinates*. This means that the texture is addressed on [0,1] in each spatial dimension. So your kernel should look this this:

```
__global__ 
void texCache_dummyKernel(float* out, const int width, const int height)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; //my index into "big image"
    int y = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idx = y*width+x;

    if(x < width && y < height) {
        float u = float(x)/float(width), v = float(y)/float(height);
        out[idx] = tex2D(tex, u, v);
    }
}
```

[Standard disclaimer: written in browser, not compiled or tested, use at own risk]

ie. you should pass coordinates to `tex2D` which are normalised by dividing through by the image width and height.

Alternatively, as you have discovered, you can change the texture definition to `normalized=false` and use addressing in absolute rather than relative textures coordinates. Even then the texture read in your code should look like this:

```
out[idx] = tex2D(tex, float(x)+0.5f, float(y)+0.5f);
```

because texture addressing is always done using floating point coordinates and the texture data is *voxel centred*, thus 0.5 is added to each coordinate to ensure the read comes from the centroid of each  interpolation area or volume within the texture.

You can find a description of texture filtering and addressing modes and their effect on interpolation in one of the appendices of the CUDA C programming guide.

Comment: How important is it to include the `+0.5f`? It seems to work equally well without the `+0.5f`, so is there some edge case where it makes a difference? (I read your explanation about the reason for `+0.5f`; I'm just asking about the ramifications of not doing it.)

Comment: @solvingPuzzles: if by "works equally well" you mean "looks like the same image", then it probably isn't important at all. If you were to do something like subtract the output from the original with the intention of getting a zero image afterwards, you will see errors. The voxel centring factory is required to produce a correct result.